# apt update 35 updates available -> no upgrade post in Artful

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 17.10, r

I upgraded to Artful yesterday and ever since ever time I run 'apt update' I get:

> Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   35 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

If I run 'apt upgrade' it does nothing but if I run 'apt list --upgradable' I get a list of packages from a statistical language called 'R'

> ~$ apt list --upgradable
>
> Listing... Done
>
> r-cran-assertthat/artful,artful 0.1-1build1 all [upgradable from: 0.1-1]
>
> r-cran-bitops/artful 1.0-6-1build1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.0-6-1]

and 33 more lines.

Any ideas anyone?

Edit: I looked at the answer to [Cannot install R on ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971533/cannot-install-r-on-ubuntu-17-10)
and tried a 'sudo aptitude full-upgrade' here are the results:

```
    $ sudo aptitude full-upgrade
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjs-jquery-metadata{a} libjs-jquery-tablesorter{a} 
  libjs-twitter-bootstrap{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  r-cran-assertthat{b} r-cran-bitops{b} r-cran-codetools{b} 
  r-cran-colorspace{b} r-cran-crayon{b} r-cran-curl{b} r-cran-dichromat{b} 
  r-cran-digest{b} r-cran-evaluate{b} r-cran-ggplot2{b} r-cran-gtable{b} 
  r-cran-labeling{b} r-cran-lazyeval{b} r-cran-learnbayes{b} 
  r-cran-magrittr{b} r-cran-munsell{b} r-cran-openssl{b} r-cran-pbdzmq{b} 
  r-cran-pkgkitten{b} r-cran-plyr{b} r-cran-r6{b} r-cran-rcolorbrewer{b} 
  r-cran-rcpp{b} r-cran-rcurl{b} r-cran-repr{b} r-cran-reshape2{b} 
  r-cran-rgtk2{b} r-cran-scales{b} r-cran-spatial{b} r-cran-stringi{b} 
  r-cran-stringr{b} r-cran-tibble{b} r-cran-uuid{b} r-cran-xml{b} 
  r-cran-xml2{b} 
35 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.8 MB of archives. After unpacking 2,413 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-xml2 : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                        - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-colorspace : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                              - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-uuid : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                        - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-labeling : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-crayon : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                          - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-rcolorbrewer : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-bitops : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                          - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-r6 : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                      - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-curl : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                        - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-reshape2 : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-gtable : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                          - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-plyr : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                        - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-xml : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                       - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-magrittr : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-rgtk2 : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                         - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-scales : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                          - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-pbdzmq : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                          - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-spatial : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                           - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-rcpp : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                        - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-assertthat : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                              - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-munsell : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                           - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-codetools : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                             - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-repr : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                        - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-digest : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                          - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-rcurl : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                         - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-stringi : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                           - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-stringr : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                           - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-evaluate : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-learnbayes : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                              - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-tibble : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                          - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-openssl : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                           - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-dichromat : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                             - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-lazyeval : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-ggplot2 : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                           - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

 r-cran-pkgkitten : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                             - r-base-core (3.4.2-1ubuntu1), but 3.4.2-2zesty is installed

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)      r-cran-assertthat [0.1-1 (now)]                    
2)      r-cran-bitops [1.0-6-1 (now)]                      
3)      r-cran-codetools [0.2-15-1 (now)]                  
4)      r-cran-colorspace [1.3-2-1 (now)]                  
5)      r-cran-crayon [1.3.2-1 (now)]                      
6)      r-cran-curl [2.3-1ubuntu2 (now)]                   
7)      r-cran-dichromat [2.0.0-3 (now)]                   
8)      r-cran-digest [0.6.12-1 (now)]                     
9)      r-cran-evaluate [0.10-1 (now)]                     
10)     r-cran-ggplot2 [2.2.1-2 (now)]                     
11)     r-cran-gtable [0.2.0-1 (now)]                      
12)     r-cran-labeling [0.3-1 (now)]                      
13)     r-cran-lazyeval [0.2.0-1 (now)]                    
14)     r-cran-learnbayes [2.15-3 (now)]                   
15)     r-cran-magrittr [1.5-3build1 (now)]                
16)     r-cran-munsell [0.4.3-1 (now)]                     
17)     r-cran-openssl [0.9.6-1 (now)]                     
18)     r-cran-pbdzmq [0.2.5+dfsg-1 (now)]                 
19)     r-cran-pkgkitten [0.1.4-1 (now)]                   
20)     r-cran-plyr [1.8.4-1 (now)]                        
21)     r-cran-r6 [2.2.0-2 (now)]                          
22)     r-cran-rcolorbrewer [1.1-2-1 (now)]                
23)     r-cran-rcpp [0.12.9-1 (now)]                       
24)     r-cran-rcurl [1.95-4.8-2 (now)]                    
25)     r-cran-repr [0.10-1 (now)]                         
26)     r-cran-reshape2 [1.4.2-1 (now)]                    
27)     r-cran-rgtk2 [2.20.31-2 (now)]                     
28)     r-cran-scales [0.4.1-1 (now)]                      
29)     r-cran-spatial [7.3-11-1zesty0 (now)]              
30)     r-cran-stringi [1.1.2-1 (now)]                     
31)     r-cran-stringr [1.1.0-1 (now)]                     
32)     r-cran-tibble [1.2-1 (now)]                        
33)     r-cran-uuid [0.1.2-8 (now)]                        
34)     r-cran-xml [3.98-1.5-1 (now)]                      
35)     r-cran-xml2 [1.1.0-1ubuntu1 (now)]                 



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Comment: How had you installed R in 17.04?

Comment: apt install  r-cran-recommended

Comment: There does not seem to be a package by that name in the Ubuntu repositories.  Is it a .deb or PPA that you got from another source?

Comment: Sorry got the name  slightly wrong, it is "r-commended" details: Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
r-recommended/now 3.4.2-2zesty all [installed,local]
  GNU R collection of recommended packages [metapackage]

Comment: K - so part of the problem is that the Ubuntu archives for Zest only supply version 3.3.2 for rbase/zesty, yet you have version 3.4.2 for Zesty.  Is there a line in your sources which looks something like `deb https://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu zesty/` where the cran mirror might be defined as [somewhere in this list](https://cran.r-project.org/)

Comment: #deb https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk//bin/linux/ubuntu/ /

Comment: The release should be specified after the `ubuntu` - try changing it to `artful`, then run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` - I gotta ron off for a bit, hope it works!

Comment: The full line would be `deb https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu artful/`

Comment: Thankyou for the replies! - tried that got the upgrade to 'r-cran-boot' but still got 35 packages not upgrading.

Comment: Hm. It looks like most of these are all dependant upon `r-base-core` which is not updating.  Perhaps `sudo apt install --reinstall r-base-core`

Comment: Now this is curious! sudo apt install --reinstall r-base-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of r-base-core is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 35 not to upgrade.

Comment: Rather bothersome...  You might review [https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) which was started from a similar question.  They suggested running `sudo apt clean` to remove all .debs, and `sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade`.  Frankly I'm at a loss, and perhaps someone with more experience can assist. FWIW, I *always* remove 3rd party PPAs and purge programs from them prior to doing upgrades.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thankyou very much for trying to help. I will continue researching this and see if I can find anything else.

Comment: I think I have finally found the cause. It seems that CRAN  has  slightly earlier versions off the packages for artful compared to those it has for zesty! I suppose time will cure this.

Comment: Hey did you by any chance find a solution? I am facing the same problem and it's rather annoying. :(